# How to make object grow only on one side when scaling?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to scale the 3d ibject from one side this problem I am going to elaborate by taking slider example. 

`As per the image when I am scaling it is scaled through center. I want to fix the left side as static and scale the slider to only right side.`

Comment: I haven't dealt a lot with scaling but doesn't changing the position of the pivot point (relative to the object) solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this objects pivot point to the left side.

I'm asuming you are talking about the `Image` component. It uses a RectTransform where you can set the pivot points like this:

[image]

or simply open that menu, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click there:

[image]

---

Or alternative make this object a child of another empty GameObject.
Set this objects position so that the left point matches the parent's pivot point. Than scale the new parent object instead.

Comment: I am talking about the 3d model. I am using capsule type of module where I need to fix one side of the model and scale the other side of the model. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Than look at the last section of my answer